# how to combine two condition in laravel elequent relation

Tags: laravel

i'm biginner in laravel, How can I combine these two conditions in the controller?
the main table is tasks that has forign key to four tables office,commander,status,priority.

```
$tasks=Task::where([['type',0]])->get();
$tasks=Task::with(['Office', 'Commander','Status','Priority'])->paginate(8);
return view('taskmanager.tasks.index',compact('tasks'));
```

Each of the two conditions in the first and second lines works fine on its own. I want to apply both together.
Tasks whose type value is zero, while the tasks table has a foreign key with the other four tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the two conditions by chaining the `where` and `with` methods together.

```php
$tasks = Task::where('type', 0)
    ->with(['Office', 'Commander', 'Status', 'Priority'])
    ->paginate(8);

return view('taskmanager.tasks.index', compact('tasks'));
```

`Task::where('type', 0)` filters the tasks where the type is 0. The `with(['Office', 'Commander', 'Status', 'Priority'])` part is eager loading the relationships, which can help reduce the number of queries to your database. Finally, `paginate(8)` will paginate the results, showing 8 tasks per page.

Answer (score -1):

> you can use both  condition like that

$tasks = Task::where(['type' => 0])->with('Office', 'Commander','Status','Priority')->paginate(8);